# Live Reload not altering style components in React Native

Tags: react-native

I have successfully set up a React Native app on an Android device, for learning purposes, and also enable Live Reload by shaking the device, and choosing the option from the dev menu. 
While this is working fine when editing Text fields and text sizes, in Visual Studio Code, each time I save App.js, Style items such as sectionTitle { color: Colors.white } don’t alter or update when I change to Colors.yellow, say.
What is going wrong here? Is Live Reload only working on part of the app??

Comment: live reload or hot reload? hot reload doesn't always work correctly; in the upcoming RN version there should be a nice improvement with React Fresh

Comment: It’s Live Reload, as Hot Reloading only covers certain parts of the app ie doesn’t save State, and so on..

Comment: actually sometimes i have to press `ctrl + s` multiple times to trigger update. i don't think it just covers some part of code, it just sometimes can't trigger update somehow

Comment: I’ve just realised - I’m using a Native Base app - don’t Native Base ‘fix’ the themes for various components?